# What is the difference between atomic and compound data types?

Tags: javascript

What is the difference between atomic and compound data types in JavaScript?

Comment: I don't see what this has to do with javascript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JavaScript (well, ECMAScript) differentiates between "primitive values" and "objects". I'm not entirely sure if that's the same as what you're thinking of, but I'm guessing so.

From the ECMAScript 5 specification, [primitive values](http://es5.github.com/#x4.3.2) are defined as follows:

> member of one of the types Undefined, Null, Boolean, Number, or String
>   as defined in Clause 8.

And [objects](http://es5.github.com/#x4.3.3) are defined as follows:

> member of the type Object.

[Section 8](http://es5.github.com/#x8) of the spec gives more details of all the types. In particular, note section 8.6:

> An Object is a collection of properties

And that's the big difference - an object is effectively a map of keys and values. Primitive values are just that - values!

Answer (score 2):

Atomic datatypes are like ints or bools they are just that atomic and not made up of sub elements.

Compound datatypes are things like array and date objects which are comprised of atomic datatypes and other functionality for manipulation.

Comment: int isn't really a JavaScript datatype, you're thinking of number. strings are also atomic. null and undefined are also atomic.